# What's a way/ways to return Identity element (that is auto-generated) in a table from a stored procedure?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have tables in my db with auto generated primary keys that I want to get a hold of when inserting new rows from my Java calling code. I'm trying to create stored procedures that handle the insertion and return back the primary key (ie. the auto-gen key) back to the calling code. I'll only be inserting one row at a time.

I have come across the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function but it seems to not be working inside a stored procedure. I most probably am using it in an incorrect way so that may also be the problem.

Here's what I put together from different sources. This doesn't compile and is in no way a correct way to do it. I'm a newbie, so it may seem like someone trying to communicate in a broken language. Please bear with me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAVER(IN PARAMETER1 VARCHAR(30), OUT ID_PARM BIGINT)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_PARAM VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE v_ID BIGINT;
SET v_PARAM=PARAMETER1;
INSERT INTO TAB_1 (NAME) VALUES (v_PARAM);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() INTO v_ID;
SET ID_PARAM=v_ID;
END
```

Another thing I'm worried about is I read somewhere that Java and DB2 don't support out parameter so I'm not sure how to return back this value.

Comment: Why do you expect a SQL Server function `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to work in Db2?

Comment: My apologies, I thought it was a SQL standard supposed to work in most DBs. What is then the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Db2 function to obtain the most recent assigned identity value is [`IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004231.html).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! If I may, would the usage of IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() be the same inside the stored procedure to return the identity value?